# Timer not stopping VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a simple Windows Forms App with Visual Studio 2019. I want to use a timer and a progress bar but i can't make the timer stop.

I've tried `Timer1.Stop()` and `Timer1.Enabled = False` but neither of them have worked. The timer waits 1 second.

Here's the full code:
(it has changed a lot but I still have the problem)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If Button1.Text = "Stop" Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
    Button1.Text = "Stop"
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Cursor = Cursors.AppStarting
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Timer1.Enabled = True Then
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    Else
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        Button1.Text = "Done!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Notice that Button1's click event always ends up enabling the timer. You probably want an Else clause in that If statement.

Comment: @CheeseCurd, code is almost unreadable in comments, especially when unformatted. If you have some code to try, try it. If it doesn't work, update the question with any new, relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you use a `CheckBox` rather than a `Button`. If you set the `Appearance` to `Button` then it will look just like a regular `Button` but you can use the `Checked` property to represent state. The control will appear depressed when `Checked` is `True`. You can then use code like this:

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    Timer1.Enabled = CheckBox1.Checked
    CheckBox1.Text = If(CheckBox1.Checked, "Stop", "Start")
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.PerformStep()

    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = False
    End If
End Sub
```